# Implement Search Everything using Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, search-engine

How the search everything kind of application is indexing & keeping track of data into its search indexes.

Recently I have been working on Apache Solr which is producing amazing results for a search. But it was for one particular products catalog section that is being searched. As Solr is a stores it's data document, we indexed searchable fields as document in solr. I'm not sure how it can be used to build a search everything kind of search? And how should I index data into Solr?

By search everything  I mean, to search into different module for information like Customers, Services, Accounts, Orders, Catalog, Support Ticket, etc. So search return results which is combined as a result from a single search form and user don't need to go into different forms for search that module?

Do I need to build different indexes for each such data models or store them into solr as single document? What is the best strategy to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store all that data in a single index with each document having an extra field that stores its type (Customer, Order, etc.). For the within-module search, just restrict the search query to documents of that type. For the Search All functionality, use copyField to copy all the relevant fields in each document type into one big field, and search with the document type field unconstrained.

Comment: @Krunal Which part are you confused about?

Comment: What fields I need to store? Does a single document will contain all the field for all modules?

Comment: Every document won't have every field, but the schema will define a document so that it *can* have any of the fields. You don't have to necessarily fill it. Alternatively you can use dynamic fields.

Comment: Okay now got it. So apart from solr docs primary unique key, I will take one more unique key pertaining to that particular module's db table. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well it won't be a unique key right? Just a field to store what type of document it is.